# Why does this error "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'" occur?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I checked my matplotlib version (3.5.7) and upgraded it, too. But this error does not go away. Default plot is shown twice and throws this error, then if run cells again, a different plot was shown twice. How do I do?

Plot was accumulated and showed error twice:

```
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

data_dir = 'LJSpeech-1.1/wavs'

data_files = [join(data_dir, f) for f in listdir(data_dir) if isfile(join(data_dir, f)) if 'wav' in f]
data_files.sort()

print('wave files : ', len(data_files))
print(data_files[0])


# return values
# wav : 오디오 신호 
# sr : sample rate, default=22050
wav, sr = librosa.core.load(data_files[1])
print('wav :', wav)

print('sample rate :', sr, 'length :', len(wav))

print('duration :', len(wav) / sr, 'seconds')

plt.figure(figsize=[18, 3])
plt.plot(wav)
plt.ylim([-1, 1])
plt.show()

# wav 들어보기
import IPython.display as ipd
ipd.Audio(wav, rate=sr)
```

[specific Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJBfF.png)

I checked my matplotlib version and upgrade. and I tried to use `plt.clf()` also. But the error keeps occurring.

Share Error with code text

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 21
     19 plt.plot(wav)
     20 plt.ylim([-1, 1])
---> 21 plt.show()
     23 # wav 들어보기
     24 import IPython.display as ipd

File ~/miniconda3/envs/audio_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:446, in show(*args, **kwargs)
    402 """
    403 Display all open figures.
    404 
   (...)
    443 explicitly there.
    444 """
    445 _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
--> 446 return _get_backend_mod().show(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/audio_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py:99, in show(close, block)
     96 # only call close('all') if any to close
     97 # close triggers gc.collect, which can be slow
     98 if close and Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
---> 99     matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')
...
    225     return props[name].__get__(instance)
--> 226 raise AttributeError(
    227     f"module {cls.__module__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/envs/audio_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py:99, in show(close, block)
     96 # only call close('all') if any to close
     97 # close triggers gc.collect, which can be slow
     98 if close and Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
---> 99     matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')

File ~/miniconda3/envs/audio_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/__init__.py:226, in caching_module_getattr..__getattr__(name)
    224 if name in props:
    225     return props[name].__get__(instance)
--> 226 raise AttributeError(
    227     f"module {cls.__module__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

Comment: Please share the code as text, not images. Make sure to include your import statements.

Comment: I'm saying you should edit your post to put the code as text, as per [this meta post on why you shouldn't share code as pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please create a fully reproducible example (in code as text), include information about the programming environment, and also share the full error trace as text.  Note that `plt.show()` should normally only be called once, at the end of the code.

Comment: ① Post your code, including your `import ...`'s using copy&paste NB it's not "Please post your code" ② Add as much context as possible, e.g., it seems that you are using Jupyter or VSCode, so tell us, etc etc.

Comment: The code itself seems fine. It seems to be a package issue. I tried changing various things in the packages, including librosa, numpy, matplotlib, and Python itself, but the result still consistently shows that 'pyplot' is not available in 'matplotlib'. error line is 21 (plt.show()) and ipd.Audio(wav, rate=sr) was not running

Comment: @SYJeong Have you tried recreating the virtual environment? There might have been an issue when you created it.

Comment: Try creating a new environment and install matplotlib and other packages when creating the environment. Also, unless this is a raspberry pi, or a micro controller with limited memory, I suggest using full anaconda instead of miniconda.

Comment: i also tried recreate virtual envrironment, but same error occured conitunally.. and tried reinstall matplotlib & numpy & numba  etc... also.. and i will try full anaconda instead of miniconda. thank you